# CkEditor removes style with strip_tags function

Tags: php

I am using ck-editor to customize text and send it via an email using php, i need to send email with colorful text and some font styles..

I am using

```
strip_tags()
```

function to remove html tags, but it removes my all styles too.
I need it to keep styles but remove tags.
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
allowable_tags: You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped.
```

Comment: but, if i use in this manner, it will add that tag in my text,,not style, is there any other way to keep styles but with hidden tags?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are saying, sorry. It will not strip off the parameters/attributes of a tag. i.e. if i have <p style='color:red'> and declare <p> in the optional parameter, the style will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

In general: "*I need it to keep styles but remove tags*" - You need tags to set styles, if no tags, no styles. Both or nothing. So it is your decision.